# How to get the body of an HTTP request?

Tags: esp32, web-server, http

I want to read a binary body datas from an HTTP POST request.

The context is that I'm making a LED strip controller and I'm currently using this code :

```cpp
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, STRIP_PIN, NEO_GRB | NEO_KHZ800);
WebServer server(80);

void handleSimpleWrite()
{
    int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
    if (server.hasArg("red"))
        r = server.arg("red").toInt();
    if (server.hasArg("green"))
        g = server.arg("green").toInt();
    if (server.hasArg("blue"))
        b = server.arg("blue").toInt();
    strip.setPixelColor(id, r, g, b);
    strip.show()
    server.send(200,"Ok");
}
```

It works, but it's clearly innefficient. I want to make an API endpoint that get a binary buffer with RGB states along the request body and I can't figure out how to read this body.

Any ideas ?

Comment: this may help ... https://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/SD-card-AJAX-XML-web-server/

Comment: esp8266 has `arg("plain")`. esp32 doesn't have it. can't you use plain WiFiServer?

Comment: @jsotola this library seem to be for AVR based Arduino, the header is unknow for my board

@Juraj I think that `arg("plain")` is stay working when looking in the source code.
I will edit [libraries/WebServer/src/Parsing.cpp](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/e1548e9b7e0b6e519a7f59052817152bfb16ab59/libraries/WebServer/src/Parsing.cpp) to fit my needs.

Comment: i send a long string of hex pairs, and it works well. use websockets instead of http to get more bandwidth.

Comment: What does efficiency mean here? -- Did you do any calculations about efficiency, if you mean speed? I mean, how fast will you change the RGB values? And how fast is the network connection? And how fast is the code you show? -- I'd leave it as is, because it is a clear and simple interface, and I assume that network and CPU are much faster than needed for this simple task.

Comment: @thebusybee you are right. I said that's not efficient because to set a different color on each LED, you need to perform an HTTP request for each LED, more than 500 in my case...

Comment: How about putting all 500 LED colors in a single POST? Even as string representation this is just a few KB, transferred in milliseconds.